# I need assistance with my PDO book database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm working on a small online system to sort my books, but stumbled upon a problem now I've been trying for hours to solve without any luck.

In my database I have a table `titles` with the book information (`title_id`, `title`, `author`...) and a second table `title_relations` with the fields `title_relation_id`, `title_id`, `to_title_id` and `titlerelation`.

When I call upon the information of a book there is a field `related titles` which is supposed to list all prequels, sequels and spin-offs.

The database looks like this:

**titles**

```
title_id  1
title     Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring
...


title_id  2
title     Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers
...


title_id  3
title     Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
...
```

**title_relations**

```
title_relation_id    1
title_id             1
to_title_id          2
titlerelation        prequel

title_relation_id    1
title_id             1
to_title_id          3
titlerelation        prequel
```

Now I'm calling up the information for *The Fellowship of the Ring* and want to be shown links to *The Two Towers* and *The Return of the King*. How do I go about getting that information there?

I got it working for one title relation, but for more than that I'd need a

```
foreach($title_relations as $row) {
}
```

where it saves the information from title_relations into variables (`$to_title_id_1`, `$titlerelation_1`, `$to_title_id_2`, `$titlerelation_2`, ...), an array or something else like that.

Nothing I tried worked, so any help offered would be highly appreciated.

I'm using PDO to get the database information.

Old code (not working):

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

if($page == 'title'){
    #titles zuordnen 
    $titles = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE title_id = $id");
    $titles->execute();

    while($row = $titles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $title = $row->title;
        /* deleted the other infos */
    }

    #title_relations zuordnen
    $title_relations = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM title_relations WHERE title_id = $id");
    $title_relations->execute();

    while($row = $title_relations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $to_title = $row->to_title_id;
        $relation_type = $row->titlerelation;
    }

    #to_title Seriennamen zuordnen
    $series_name = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE title_id = $to_title");
    $series_name->execute();

    while($row = $series_name->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $series = $row->title;
    }
}

#Datenbank schließen
$dbh = null; } catch(PDOException $exceptionpdo){
echo 'ERROR: ' . $exceptionpdo->getMessage(); }
```

Current code (working!):

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    if($page == 'title'){
        // titles zuordnen
        // Here I binded the $id in execute, not in prepare
        $titles = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title FROM titles WHERE title_id = ?");
        $titles->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $titles->execute();

        // Here you are expecting a single row, I guess title_id is a primary key, so you don't needa loop
        $row = $titles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $title = $row->title;

        // title_relations zuordnen
        $title_relations = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title_relation_id, title_id, to_title_id, titlerelation FROM title_relations WHERE title_id = ?");
        $title_relations->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $title_relations->execute();

        $series = array(); // In this array we will store all the related titles

        while($row = $title_relations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            // zu_title Serieninfo zuordnen
            $series_info = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title_id, title FROM titles WHERE title_id = ?");
            $series_info->bindParam(1, $row->to_title_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $series_info->execute();

            while($row = $series_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $series[] = $row;           
            }
        }

    #Datenbank schließen
    $dbh = null;
}

} catch(PDOException $exceptionpdo){
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $exceptionpdo->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you got it working for one title relation, please?

Comment: Please, show your query. Do you use `JOIN`?

Comment: Shouldn't you have stored the reverse relationship somewhere `(title_id=2, to_title_id=1, titlerelation=sequel)`?

Comment: @minitech Thanks for fixing up my thread a bit :)

Added my current code just now (which took pathetically long because I'm still not used to the markup on here v.v)

Comment: @v.kondratyuk Haven't used it so far. What would be the use of that in this case?

Comment: @Wrikken For now I just wanted to get it down in one direction and later simply add on to that code by checking the `to_title_id` after the `title_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoul supply your query to better understand and adapt this answer to your specific needs.
Without that the simplest example I can think of, basicaly you use just one query with left join to return the title even if it has no relations (good for simple smaller tables). In this example I just print the related titles to STDOUT with an identation.

```
// Your get this from whatever, $_GET ... etc ...
$title_id = 1; // exemple id1 = Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring

$sth = $dbh->prepare('select t1.title, t2.title
       from titles as t1
       left join title_relations as trel on (t1.title_id=trel.title_id)
       left join titles as t2 on (t2.title_id=trel.to_title_id)
       where t1.title_id=?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $title_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

// original title
echo $result[0]['title'];

// related title
foreach($results as $row)
{
    echo "\t".$row['title'];
}
```

**@update

Based on your code, a working version would be:

@disclaimer, this is based on your code, I am not recomanding to do select in a while loop, I will just use a single query like the version above (or a variation of it).**

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $dbh->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    if($page == 'title')
    {
        $series = array(); // In this array we will store all the related titles

        // titles zuordnen
        // Here I binded the $id in execute, not in prepare
        $titles = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title_id, title, author /*put your other columns*/ FROM titles WHERE title_id = ?");
        $titles->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $titles->execute();

        // Here you are expecting a single row, I guess title_id is a primary key, so you don't needa loop
        $row = $titles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $title = $row->title;
        /* deleted the other infos */

        // title_relations zuordnen
        $title_relations = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title_relation_id, title_id, to_title_id, titlerelation FROM title_relations WHERE title_id = ?");
        $title_relations->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $title_relations->execute();

        while($row = $title_relations->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
        {
            // This is in a loop, it will store just the value from the last row !
            // $relation_type = $row->titlerelation;

            // to_title Seriennamen zuordnen
            $series_name = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title_id, title, author /*put your other columns*/ FROM titles WHERE title_id = ?");
            $series_name->bindParam(1, $row->to_title_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $series_name->execute();    

            while($row = $series_name->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {
                // $series = will store the values just from the last row, changed it to an array to store all relations
                $series[$row->title_id] = $row->title;
            }
        }
    }

    // Datenbank schließen
    $dbh = null;
} catch(PDOException $exceptionpdo)
{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $exceptionpdo->getMessage();
}
```

Your code return just one relation because you query-ed just the last row returned from title_relations. To solve this (`again in the context of your code`) I moved the last query in the while of title_relations.
To be able to acces all relations I made an `(array)$series`, you just store the last row in the `(string)$series`.

Comment: I've added the relevant code to my post. Thought it would be better without so as not to hinder you guys' thoughts. Seems I was wrong ^^

In your example you're directly outputting the results, would you know a way to save them into variables/an array for later use?

Comment: @spiel: update working code based on your original code, if you have any other unclarities please ask.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this! Works like a charm with a bit of tweaking :D

I had to move the bindings like so `$titles->bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` because I got the following error message `Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 parameter, 3 given in xxx.php on line 86`.

I put the whole updated code at the bottom of my original question.

Comment: Two questions though (only if you have the time of course):

- Why do you write out all the column names in the SELECT query instead of using * to select them all?
Especially confusing to me because for the variable `$title_relations` we need all the columns anyway.

Comment: - What is the reason you took out `$id` from the query and bound in execute?
I can't even see it as saving work for when I'm changing variables, as any new `?` would not be `1` anymore but the next number, so I'd have to bind them one by one either way. (So yeah, I guess the basic question is why do we bind parameters to begin with? I don't see the bonus in this case.)

I'm sorry if these questions seem stupid, this is my first time using PDO and to begin with I have only the most basic understanding of sql u.u"

Comment: @spiel: Please google them, you will find a lot of good articles online. Long story short: 1) If you will add more columns in the database, it will not break your query (2 columns same name in different tables) or select more rows the actualy needed (this save time, memory and bandwitch). 2) For security, if will protect you against "sql injections" and it will speed up by catching the query and validate it's syntax only once, for example prepare once, bind and execute many times the same query.

Comment: @spiel: Sorry for the execute without bind, it was a typo, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able traverse these relations in both directions (prequel / sequel) so you need to search by `to_title_id` as well as by `title_id`.

`SELECT * FROM title_relations WHERE title_id = ? OR to_title_id = ?`

To recurse, and see *The Return of the King* from *The Fellowship of the Ring* your best bet is probably to run a second query (and a third if you want to go deeper) then cache the results in a json array/hash structure using something like memcache. However, to do this for *Harry Potter* or the *Foundation* series the recursion gets a bit out of hand, let alone if you have any *Star Trek* novels.

I've done something similar from my own library project, but I used a `series` table and a `title_series` table that stores each title's order in the series. Then it only takes one query to find the related titles.

Comment: Yep, the `to_title_id` will be added once I get the first part working :)

I haven't even ever heard of memcache, this will need some reading up on :s